# why some of bindable property is not valid?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I created bindable property but one of them can not be found while others is all work fine.

```
public string Username { get => (string)GetValue(UserNameProperty); set => SetValue(UserNameProperty, value); }
public static readonly BindableProperty UserNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(LiveView.Username), typeof(string), typeof(LiveView), null);
```

it tells me that No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Username', or mismatching type between value and property.

Is it a wrong statement?

but another property names Title and UserImage is ok while the three statement is all using the right method.

Comment: In the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties), it says: `The naming convention for bindable properties is that the bindable property identifier must match the property name specified in the Create method, with "Property" appended to it.` So change your Username to UserName.

Comment: Yes you are right .Thank you Jack Hua.you are a microsoft officer too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below statement.

public string UserName { get => (string)GetValue(UserNameProperty); set => SetValue(UserNameProperty, value); }

Note: try to declare CLR property name same as BindableProperty prefix statement.

Comment: it supporse to be very right. but my vs for mac seems to be something not ok.since I changed the name "Username" to "UserName" it says "UserName" was not found after I rebuild the project.